# JSON conditional count in Python

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON file >>

```
[
{
    "Name": "xyz", 
    "member": {
        "Date": "2017-10-02T15:20:29Z", 
        "enrolled": false
    }, 
    "postalCode": "5554", 
    "id": 77
}...
```

Within the JSON I would like to count the number of times 'enrolled'='true' in the 'member' element.

This is the code I have which doesn't seem to work.

```
c = json.loads(b)
print(sum([1 for i in c['member'] if i['enrolled'] == 'true']))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ``enrolled`` is a boolean in your JSON, so after converting it to an object, it will also be a Boolean in Python (``True`` instead of ``'true'``).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate each dict in the list.

Use:

```
import json

b = """[
{
    "Name": "xyz", 
    "member": {
        "Date": "2017-10-02T15:20:29Z", 
        "enrolled": false
    }, 
    "postalCode": "5554", 
    "id": 77
}]"""

c = json.loads(b)
print(sum(1 for i in c if i['member']['enrolled']))
```